# How to create dynamic Steps from JSON stored in DB for Spring Batch application using java 1.8? So, the steps will be created after job launch

Tags: json, java-8, spring-batch

I have to create the steps after launching the Job. My Job Parameters will get me the JSON from DB which contains the Steps and Substeps. If the step isn't there in JSON I don't have to include it in my Job. The steps can be in random order, customer can change the order of steps.

I have created the customized job factory which will return me the Flow, so if there are File related tasks I'll read JSON for it and create/ include flow in the main Job. With this approach I am not able to query the DB after job launch, the query for JSON got ran at Job Configuration time (using Annotations).

Then I have written Deciders for each step, and added all the deciders in Job and Continue for that particular Step.  But here I lost the step order dynamism.

```
jobbuilderFactory.get("DynamicJob").start(bootstrapData())
.next(step1Decider).on("CONTINUE").to(step1Execution())
.next(step2Decider).on("CONTINUE").to(step2Execution())
.
.
.end().build();
```

What I am trying to get
1. User will launch the job with some parameters
2. get the JSON from DB using Job Parameter values
3. read/ parse JSON to create the Steps and include them in the Job
4. Start Job execution

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you are trying to dynamically create Spring beans from a JSON input, so your job definition is dynamic and depends on job parameters. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, we can create all Step Beans and loop only those which are present in JSON. The JSON that I have to fetch from the database on the basis of JobParameters passed to Job.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification. I added an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Once you defined all your steps from the JSON, you can dynamically create the job definition as follows:

```
Step bootstrapData, step1, step2;

JobFlowBuilder jobBuilder = jobBuilderFactory.get("myjob").flow(bootstrapData);
if (someCondition()) {
    jobBuilder.next(step1);
}
if (someOtherCondition()) {
    jobBuilder.on("CONTINUE").to(step2);
}

// etc
```

Comment: Yes, we can have the Steps array and can add to the job.  But, here I want to create the Steps using JobParamertes.  So when my Job Bean got Configured how to access the JobParameters.